# Java ssh2 connection to remote mysql server from eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

have been troubled by this for quite sometime, with reference to the code from here: http://www.journaldev.com/235/java-program-to-connect-to-remote-database-through-ssh-using-port-forwarding
have been trying, but still unable to get the connection. Here's my modified code:

```
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
    import java.sql.Connection;

    public class MySqlConnOverSSH {

    /**
    * Java Program to connect to remote database through SSH using port forwarding
    * @throws SQLException 
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    int lport=5656;
    String rhost="fictitious@germany.com";
    String host="fictitious@germany.com";
    int rport=3306;
    String user="root";
    String password="root";
    String dbuserName = "root";
    String dbpassword = "root";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+lport+"/test";
    String driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Connection conn = null;
    Session session= null;
    try{
        //Set StrictHostKeyChecking property to no to avoid UnknownHostKey issue
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        int assigned_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
        System.out.println("localhost:"+assigned_port+" -> "+rhost+":"+rport);
        System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

        //mysql database connectivity
        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, dbuserName, dbpassword);
        System.out.println ("Database connection established");
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(conn != null && !conn.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
            conn.close();
        }
        if(session !=null && session.isConnected()){
            System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

and following is the error which i get:

```
    Connected
    localhost:5656 -> fictitious@germany.com:3306
    Port Forwarded
    java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'fictitious@germany.com' (using password: YES)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:121)Closing SSH Connection

at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:69)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:110)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at myDB.MySqlConnOverSSH.main(MySqlConnOverSSH.java:50)
    Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'fictitious@germany.com' (using password: YES)
at  org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.authentication(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:433)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:397)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:318)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:630)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:580)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:105)
... 3 more}
```

I am at Java:beginner level and trying to explore different ways to get this connection going. By the way, I am able to connect to the database using the given Username and password on SecureCRT, so the authorization error is kind of confusing. It would be great if someone could guide me in what I'm doing wrong and how it could be corrected. Thanks a ton in advance !

Comment: i think you dont have access permission for database from `'root'@'fictitious@germany.com' `

Comment: Hi Atmish-E-Azam, I thought the same too at first. But as I mentioned I am able to access via SecureCRT (SecureCRT is a rock-solid terminal emulator and telnet/SSH client for Windows, Mac, and Linux) using the same login data. Does it need special permission from Java ?

Comment: why are you using ssh and mysql connection both ?? I think u can directly connect db from java class.

Comment: Its a remote Server and I want to learn SSH connection in Java.